# make div and image vertically align inside a div

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="outside" style="width: 500px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <img src="" style="width: 10px; height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block;">
    <div id="here" style="display: inline-block; height: 15px; border: 1px solid blue; font-size: 7px;">11</div>
</div>
```

I found bottom line of  img and #here do not in a line, if I add any text to #here, who can tell me why.
And how to make the #here and img verticall center in the outside (img and #here in the same line )

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` is what you are looking for.

```css
.outside > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside" style="width: 500px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/20/10" style="width: 10px; height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block;">
  <div id="here" style="display: inline-block; height: 15px; border: 1px solid blue; font-size: 7px;">11</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it in the horizontal center?

```css
#ImageCtr {
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    
}
#outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="ImageCtr"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vCVDBHB.png">
    </div>
</div>
```